# Dependency Injection into global.asax

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, webforms, global-asax

Injecting dependencies in Global.asax does not seem to always work. **Sometimes it does, sometimes I get a ContextDisposedException** (it seems that the problem occurs when I'm doing a Page.Redirect ??). I'm in an *ASP.NET WebForm* context.

Here is my code:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    [Inject]
    public UserManager UserManager { get; set; }

    private void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            GlobalSecurityContext.SetPrincipal(User);

            string path = Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
            if (path.Contains(".aspx"))
            {
                // Get the current user
                var userData = UserManager.GetByIdWithLogin(User.Identity.Name);
                if (userData != null)
                {
                    LoginDataDTO data = userData.LoginData; 
                    if (data.XXX && ...)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect(...);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserManager.Logout();
    }
}
```

In this post [How to inject dependencies into the global.asax.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752023/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-the-global-asax-cs), Mark Seemann says that one should not use Dependency Injection in global.asax because global.asax IS the *Composition Root*.

So what is the best way to solve my problem since I don't want to directly call my UserManager because the constructor needs a repository

```
public UserManager(IGenericRepository repository) : base(repository)
{
}
```

and the `GenericRepository` has itself a constructor that needs a `IContext`

```
public GenericRepository(IContext context)
{
}
```

I could probably do `new UserManager(new GenericRepository(new MyContext))` but

1. I will not reuse the same context for the whole request
2. I need to add a reference on my AccessLayer in the GUI, what I would like to avoid

Just as an information, currently I'm injecting the Context like this:

```
// Dynamically load the context so that we dont have a direct reference on it!
string contextType = // read type from web.config
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contextType))
{
    Type context = Type.GetType(contextType);
    Bind<IContext>().To(context).InRequestScope();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

***[Edit]:***

Changing the UserProperty property like this works:

```
public UserManager UserManager
{
    get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UserManager>(); }
}
```

Comment: I concur that the Global.asax is the entry point - the composition root. You wire up your dependencies there, so you can't *inject* anything. I'd just use `Resolve` method of your IoC container to get the instance you need.

Comment: This is like asking, why can't I use the DI container before I created it :-P

Comment: Steven: The DI Container is created OnStart, so it should be available in my PostAuthenticate method, isn't it? And as I wrote, most of the time this code is working... it just fails sometimes.

Comment: @Bidou 'Fails sometimes' is not a very good description. Give us an exception. And if you can't, then there's your problem - have a search for ELMAH etc.

Comment: Ruben: This is what I did... "Sometimes it does, sometimes I get a ContextDisposedException (it seems that the problem occurs when I'm doing a Page.Redirect ??)."

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can build your Ninject container, and use it a Service Locator for this particular instance (since you're in the Composition Root - you can't inject anything at this point).